# Dynamically add named mapping to Index

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I would like to add mappings to an index after I've created it. I've created the index as such:

```
client.CreateIndex("typeaheads", c => c
                         .Settings(t => t.Analysis(m => m.TokenFilters(fl => fl.EdgeNGram("edge_ngram_filter", ad => ad.MinGram(2).MaxGram(20)))
                         .Analyzers(anz => anz.Custom("edge_ngram_analyzer", an => an.Filters("lowercase", "edge_ngram_filter").Tokenizer("standard"))))));
```

The variable typeName, is the name I want for the mapping.

When I execute this:

```
var map = new CreateIndexDescriptor("typeaheads")
                               .Mappings(ms => ms
                               .Map(typeName, d => d.Properties(ps => ps.String(s => s.Name("countryCode")))
                               .Properties(ps => ps.String(s => s.Name("display_ID")))
                               .Properties(ps => ps.String(s => s.Name("display_String")))
                               .Properties(ps => ps.String(s => s.Name("id")))
                               .Properties(ps => ps.String(s => s.Name("languageCode")))
                               .Properties(ps => ps.String(s => s.Name("match_String").SearchAnalyzer("standard").Index(FieldIndexOption.Analyzed).Analyzer("edge_ngram_analyzer")))
                               .Properties(ps => ps.String(s => s.Name("type")))
                               .Properties(ps => ps.Number(s => s.Name("boostFactor").Type(NumberType.Long)))));
var response = client.Index(map);
```

I get this output on my ES service:
[Wrong Mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDotn.png)

I would like to get this: [Correct Mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S87Nx.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: could you provide mapping as JSON?

Comment: How would that be done through C#?

Comment: You can post the json in client.

Comment: Could you show me an example?

Comment: Try https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/auto-map.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an existing index and wish to add a mapping to it, this can be done with the [Put Mapping API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html), exposed in NEST as `client.Map<T>()` and `client.MapAsync<T>()`

```
var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool);              
var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

var typeName = "my-type";

var mappingResponse = client.Map<object>(d => d
    .Index("typeaheads")
    .Type(typeName)
    .Properties(ps => ps
        .String(s => s.Name("countryCode"))
        .String(s => s.Name("display_ID"))
        .String(s => s.Name("display_String"))
        .String(s => s.Name("id"))
        .String(s => s.Name("languageCode"))
        .String(s => s
            .Name("match_String")
            .SearchAnalyzer("standard")
            .Index(FieldIndexOption.Analyzed)
            .Analyzer("edge_ngram_analyzer")
        )
        .String(s => s.Name("type"))
        .Number(s => s
            .Name("boostFactor")
            .Type(NumberType.Long)
        )
    )
);
```

which sends the following request

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/typeaheads/my-type/_mapping?pretty=true 
{
  "properties": {
    "countryCode": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "display_ID": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "display_String": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "id": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "languageCode": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "match_String": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "analyzed",
      "analyzer": "edge_ngram_analyzer",
      "search_analyzer": "standard"
    },
    "type": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "boostFactor": {
      "type": "long"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this did work. I thought that the mapping would take the name of the object name specified in `Map<object>`. But I guess, its overridden by setting the `.Type()`, right?

Comment: The type will be inferred from `T` in `Map<T>()`, correct; by default NEST lowercases the POCO type name, and as you have stated, this can be overridden by calling `.Type(TypeName typename)`. I used `object` in the example as it wasn't clear if you have a POCO to represent your document.