# How to map an Array to an Object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm using array.map to iterate through DOM elements in nodejs/cheerio.

There is my code:

```
const $ = cheerio.load(html);
const lis = $("table[id*='sortable-']").find('tr');

const lisy = lis.map((i, li) => {
  var name = $(li).find('td.h-text-left.over-s-only').text();
  var cnt = $(li).text();

  return {
   content: cnt
  }
}).get();
```

And now, I want to return named objects by "name" variable, but for now, .map returning iterated objects:

```
0: {"cnt": content}, 1: {"cnt": content}
```

Insted of this, I want to get objects indexed by every "name" like this:

```
name: {"cnt": content}, name: {"cnt": content}
```

Is it possible to name returned object like this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585611/dynamically-add-named-mapping-to-index
may be helpful.

Comment: `map` returns an array. `0` and `1` are indices of that array. You're trying to create an object with keys `nm` only? That's simply not possible because object cannot contain duplicate keys. Please define your problem clearly.

Comment: nm is variable containing different strings.. It depends of $(li).find('td.h-text-left.over-s-only').text();
I have edited example objects

Comment: Please accept the answer, which helped you best. SO questions should have an accepted answer. Thx

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your goal by using [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
var result = lis.reduce(function(map, li) {
    var name = $(li).find('td.h-text-left.over-s-only').text();
    var cnt = $(li).text();
    map[name] = { content: cnt };
    return map;
}, {});
```